# creating new image objects in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, picturebox

I am currently working on a WPF application where I want the user to be able to click a button that places an image to the screen.

Currently I have a group box area which I want the images to show up. When the user click the "Another Picture" button, a new image object is created inside the group box and another picture is displayed within the group box (with the previous one still beside it). I am thinking that using the group box would work best so that the images will re-size automatically by the number of objects in the group box.

Really all i need to know is, is it possible to create an image object through the xaml.cs and if so how can i do it (and get it to go inside of the specified group box)

Thanks

Comment: Check out [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) & [templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your looking for this:

```
Image i = new Image();     
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(); 
bi.BeginInit(); 
bi.UriSource = new Uri("plane.png", UriKind.Relative); 
bi.EndInit(); 
i.Source = bi;
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx

Comment: Image i = new Image(); only work with System.Windows.Controls.Image